# Item Level/Parent Grouping in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

Is there a way in PowerBI  to create a table with Level/Parent grouping like in the excel screenshots below?

Note the Totals for Cats and Dogs are **not** the sum of their sub levels. The data I'm working with is not additive. I'd like to implement this parent/child structure in drop down filters too if possible - extra kudos for that.

[image]

[image]

Cheers!

Animal,Score

Dogs,55

Rover,63

Lassie,56

Scoobie,14

Champ,26

Cats,29

Mr Bigglesworth,81

Top Cat,96

Bag Puss,52

Comment: https://www.daxpatterns.com/parent-child-hierarchies/

Comment: Can you paste your data as copiable text. If the data is not additive, what are the totals?

Comment: Hi, the data is just examples I made up. but a good example, would be the number of people watching each team in the world cup. the number of people watching European Teams games would be less than the sum of people watching each of the European countries games. because some people would watch games by more than one country.
I'll add the data now...